# In some Android phones, the Google Play Store displays my app's old version logo

Tags: android, google-play, updates, google-play-console

Users have updated the app multiple times, and they are using the latest version of the app. They update their app successfully, but the app's logo and name doesn't change in the Google Play Store (on some phones). When I search for my app on the [Google Play Store Web](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tezish.googleplay&pli=1), I see the updated version, but when I search for it on phones, I see the old one.
How can I resolve this issue?
Click to see:[Google Play in web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Beg89.png),
[Google Play in phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdJWF.jpg).
I have contacted Google Play Console support, and they stated that users need to clear the cache of the app to see the new version. However, this is not a viable solution. I cannot ask users to spend a few minutes clearing the app's cache just to view the updated icon.